# Altium Designer "Unknown Pin Error" for component

Tags: altium, footprint

I could not use vias to make test points from Altium Test Point Manager.

I decided to put test point from the schematic, by making a component called test point in my own library. When I import the component from schematic, it works for the first test point TP1.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for other test points.

[image: TESTPOINTPAD]

I have checked the name designator in both schematic and footprint. I don't see any mistake.

[image: Symbol]

[image: Footprint]

I also saw this message in Altium, which I did not understand:

[image: Messege]

I am new to Altium. Hope to hear from you guys.

Comment: Are you sure about your first sentence?  Any via can be assigned as a test point in its properties, and they should show up in the test point report.  HOWEVER, it is a very manual process, but it's a part of design because you have to make sure your test points are properly spaced and sized for your ICT.

Comment: @peterSmith Sorry, I should have more clear . I can set via as point properties, but not from the design rule. Therefore, I could not alocate them automatically from test manger.